# How to create an SVM for my data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I want to transfer my binned data into a SVM to predict the weight of a individual based off of hundreds of features like height, age, etc.

Currently, my binned data (I used groupby(pd.cut)) includes the weight as part of its data. Also, my data includes a few NaNs. I want to know:

1. How to separate my data into X and Y(labels)
2. Which SVM would be best for my objective
3. How to replace the NaNs with the mean value (I believe I would need to use the Imputer module?)

Thanks in advance, and also I am new to programming as a whole so please assume that I know only the basics.

Comment: Your question has some problems.  First, it's more than one question.  Second, we don't make product recommendations.  Third, what's an SVM?  Don't just assume that we know what you're talking about.

Comment: A SVM is a support vector machine, it's a type of machine learning algorithm,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume you have an X of shape [samples, features]. In this case, you need to know the index of the weight feature, and then extract it. Something like this should work.

   ```
   y = Xorg[:,weightind]
   X = np.delete(X, weightind, 1)
   ```
2. Weight is a continuous variable. Unless you want to convert it into classification categories (e.g., "slim", "normal", "heavy") - you need a regressor. I don't know why you're so keen on SVM, but there is an SVM regressor - [SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html). If your question is about a kernel for the SVR - you can try a few with [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html).
3. Yes, you'll need the imputer model. A simple usage (replacing with mean) would be:

   ```
   Ximp = Imputer().fit_transform(X)
   ```

Comment: Are there any specific regressors in sklearn that you would recommend? Also, are there any feature selectors that you would recommend as well? Thanks!

Comment: @user3712008 Not in particular, and that really depends on the nature of your data. Anyway, if the answer was helpful, please accept it.